# Сравнить значения элемента массива с предыдущим

Tags: php

Здравствуйте. Есть txt файл, который содержит в себе множество строк.
Вывожу этот файл на страницу, разбивая на строки.
После чего я выбираю только те строки, элементы массива, которые состоят из 20 элементов.
Беру первое и второе слово(это дата и время) с каждой строки.
И получается нечто вроде:

```
2018/01/15 15:00:00
2018/01/15 15:00:00
2018/01/15 16:00:00
2018/01/15 18:00:00
2018/01/15 18:00:00
```

Мне нужно чтобы получилось на выходе только строки с разной датой:

```
2018/01/15 15:00:00
2018/01/15 16:00:00
2018/01/15 18:00:00

$log = file_get_contents('./file.txt', FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);
$line = explode("\n", $log);

foreach ($line as &$value_line) {

    $arr_line = explode(' ', $value_line);

    if (count($arr_line) == 20) {

        $dateTime = $arr_line[0]." ".$arr_line[1];

        echo $dateTime;

        echo "<hr>";

    }

}
```

Как мне это сделать?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/class.ds-set.php ?

Comment: я полагаю что можно использовать `for` вместо `foreach`

Comment: Заведите переменную в которой будете хранить предыдущую дату. и сравнивайте с ней. типа `if($old != $dateTime) { echo "$dateTime<hr>"; } $old=$dateTime;`

Comment: или выводить строки `if (strcmp($dateTime; $arr_line[0]." ".$arr_line[1]))`

Comment: @Денис а строки отсортированы на входе?

Comment: @splash58 да, отсортированы по дате

Comment: @splash58 сработало бы просто сравнение с предыдущей строкой...

Comment: тогда, действительно, всё просто - делайте, например, как у Mike в комментарии

Comment: вот так, например `$old=$dateTime;`  а перед циклом $old = '';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо вводить вспомогательную переменную, например массив:

```
$datas = array();

foreach ($line as &$value_line) {

    $arr_line = explode(' ', $value_line);

    if (count($arr_line) == 20) {

        $dateTime = $arr_line[0]." ".$arr_line[1];

        if( !in_array( $dateTime , $datas) ){
            $datas[] = $dateTime;
            echo $dateTime;
            echo "<hr>";
        }
    }
}
```

Или строку:

```
$before = '';

foreach ($line as &$value_line) {

    $arr_line = explode(' ', $value_line);

    if (count($arr_line) == 20) {

        $dateTime = $arr_line[0]." ".$arr_line[1];

        if( $dateTime != $before ){
            $before = $dateTime;
            echo $dateTime;
            echo "<hr>";
        }
    }
}
```

Но строка если одинаковые даты идут только подряд

Comment: да переменная и так есть `$dateTime ` она хранит прошлый элемент, а вот чтоб работало в любом случае, а не только для соседних строк , тогда.. каждую выводимую строку сохранять в массив и выводить следующую строку если строки в массиве нет. добавляем перебор в этом массиве через дополнительный `foreach`.. но в вопросе указали что строки отсортированы, тогда цикл не нужен